# angular 1.5 component to call the parent scope method

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, components, parent

I have a html template + controller.
I added there a component:

```
<ir irtrend="addIrTrend"></ir>
```

addIrTrend is a function in my controller scope.
I want my component to call the addIrTrend method.
I give my component the irtrend parameter like this:

```
bindings: {
    irtrend: '&'
}
```

and it has an element that has ng-click on it:

```
<td ng-repeat="item in items" ng-click="$ctrl.irtrend({item: item}">
```

As I understand, when clicking on the td element, the irtrend method 
which references to the parent ctrl "addIrTrend" method, should be called.

Actually nothing happens.

Any idea ?

Thanks !

Comment: Is your example code correct? That list piece with the ng-click, the function doesn't have a closing parenthesis.

Answer (score 1):

Actually in `irtrend` attribute you should be specifying method call.

```
<ir irtrend="addIrTrend(item)"></ir>
```

Also correct `ng-click` expression to close parenthesis `$ctrl.irtrend({item: item})`